# SVN: How do I link part of my source to another repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

Say my trunk refers to Hibernate and I would like to use the source directly in my repository from sourceforge and whenever I do a svn update it should also update hibernate from its source
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do so with externals.
Set them up with a command like this:

```
svn propset svn:externals dest-folder http://your-other-repository
```

You can find the documentation on externals in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: There are also other tools (piston/steam) that can be used for a "more flexible" svn:externals. If you do use svn:externals, *please, please, please* make sure you checkout a specific revision or tag! (Actually, I don't care much, but it may save you some headaches in the future.)

Comment: @pst when you say get specific revision - I would say that it only accounts to some deployment scenarios. In my scenario I need to have the latest file - its a case of a forced duplication of same src file in repo.